# Change Encoding and Move Files in ONE bash Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vim

I'm currently going through a manual process of encoding a file list from DOS to Unix so that I can move files from x to y. I would like this process automated in one script but I'm a total noob.

This is the pseudo-code:

1. Convert `list.txt` to unix encoding (`:set ff=unix`)
2. Move files from `/folder` that are present in `list.txt` to
       `/folder2` (in other words, `/folder` contains a big list, but i
       only want the files in `list.txt` to be moved)

   this is how i'm moving the files: `while read line ; do cp /opt/home/first.last/Runs/clientPDFs/${line}.pdf ~/folder2 ; done < ~/list.txt`

If possible I would like the script to check for `list.txt` first. If there isn't one it should move ALL files.

**if** `list.txt` **then** `while read line ; do cp /opt/home/first.last/Runs/clientPDFs/${line}.pdf ~/folder2 ; done < ~/list.txt`

**else** `while read line ; do cp /opt/home/first.last/Runs/clientPDFs/${line}.pdf ~/folder2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably structure it something like this:

```
filelist="list.txt"
srcdir="/opt/home/first.last/Runs/clientPDFs"
dstdir="$HOME"

if [ -r "$filelist" ]; then
  sed 's/\r$//' "$filelist" | xargs -I{} cp -t "$dstdir"/ -- "$srcdir"/{}.pdf
else
  cp -t "$dstdir"/ -- "$srcdir"/*.pdf
fi
```

You could append the pdf extension within the sed command if you prefer i.e.

```
  sed 's/\r$/.pdf/' "$filelist" | xargs -I{} cp -t "$dstdir" -- "$srcdir"/{}
```

Comment: thanks but I have a question. Is the list converted to Unix encoding anywhere?

Comment: @reddish the `sed` command removes trailing carriage return (`\r`) characters - that should be exactly equivalent to vi's `set ff=unix` except that it's done 'on the fly': if you want to actually modify the contents of the file on disk, then add `-i` (or `--in-place`) to the `sed` command - or replace it altogether with `dos2unix` for example.